# WSO2 EI - Best Practice for Creating Data Sources

Tags: wso2, erp, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

For an ERP system which has a huge database, what is the best practice to create a Data source? I want to create quite a few endpoints on the Enterprise Integrator. Wanted to know which is the best practice:
1. One database connection which will be shared by all the endpoints OR
2. Single connection for each endpoint which has access to only those database tables which it needs?